# Javascript Function not defined outside jquery onready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are my js file and two divs, I don't understand why html2 doesn'work, I get "sendMessage Is Not defined". Someone can explain it to me... or just a link to explain.

Thanks

```
    $(function() {

        var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket

        var wsUrl = jsRoutes.controllers.P2.connect().absoluteURL();
        wsUrl = wsUrl.replace("http", "ws");

        var p2Socket = new WS(wsUrl)

        var sendMessage = function() {
            p2Socket.send(JSON.stringify(
                {text: "HI"}
            ))

        }   

            $("#buttonHi" ).click(function() {
             sendMessage()
             });
    });

function sendMessageOutside(){
         sendMessage();
}
```

And Html 1 ...

```
<div id="p2-console" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <button id="buttonHi" >Interact</button>
</div>
```

And Html 2 ...

```
<div id="p2-console" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <button id="buttonHi" onclick="sendMessageOutside()">Interact</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Put `sendMessageOutside()` also within "`document.ready`", and use proper event attaching technique. This way you can avoid all globals.

Comment: The simplest fix is to change `var sendMessage = function() {` to `window.sendMessage = function() {` then it will "just work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining sendmessage locally within your jquery function it can't be seen outside that scope by the sendMessageOutside() function. You need to define sendmessage as a global variable then try it.

```
    var sendmessage;
     $(function() {

        var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket

        var wsUrl = jsRoutes.controllers.P2.connect().absoluteURL();
        wsUrl = wsUrl.replace("http", "ws");

        var p2Socket = new WS(wsUrl)

            sendMessage = function() {
            p2Socket.send(JSON.stringify(
                {text: "HI"}
            ))

        }   

            $("#buttonHi" ).click(function() {
             sendMessage()
             });
    });

function sendMessageOutside(){
         sendMessage();
}
```

Comment: That's a good explanation about the issue, but maybe not the best solution, since it creates the function in global scope. I think a better way would be to attach the function to the event in code.